# Rendering a pspicture inside another document

Tags: pstricks, pst-barcode, pspicture

I have a C++ program that generates a PDF via LaTeX by writing the data to stdout and piping to pdflatex -shell-escape.

The template looks like this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf,pst-barcode}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-0.7in}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.600000in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{8.0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{11in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{0ex}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3.61in}p{3.39in}}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}

\multicolumn{5}{l}{Item1: .; Item2: .; Item3: .}\\
\end{tabular} & 
\begin{tabular}{c}
{\Huge\textbf{100}}\\
\begin{pspicture}(0.7,0.7)
\psbarcode{100}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
{\Huge\textbf{}}\\
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}



\clearpage
\end{document}
```

When I attempt to compile this I get 
"Package pst-pdf Warning: pspicture No. 1 undefined."

The rest of the document is generated but the embedded QR code is not.

Sorry for the large example, but the pspicture statements on their own work just fine so I'm not sure which part of the document is causing it to not work.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try `\psbarcode{100}{}{qrcode}`

Comment: Write this as an answer!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! However, I tried this and I still get the same error.

Comment: So after a bit more testing it looks like I'm doing something else wrong -- if i 'pipe' this output to pdflatex (as opposed to storing it in a tex file and compiling the text file), *that* breaks it. however, storing it in a tex file and then compiling it works fine.

Comment: @George  you should make that an answer.